# rails Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded for qr_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, google-app-engine, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working in Ruby on rails application. We are using the URL Shortener API using "**gem googl**"
and have signed up and created a project for it. We have enabled the API and have created a Public API Access key.
We have whitelisted the domains that are allowed to call. We are using an individual google developer console account. Not business.

Everything worked fine the first 2 or 3 days. Then suddenly we started to get this error message every call we do:

`Exception: {"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message"=>"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", "extendedHelp"=>"https://code.google.com/apis/console"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."}}`

We have google all different forums for this error. But have not found the solution.

What do we need to do?

Comment: Looks like you're not doing the authentication properly, because registered apps get a 1,000,000 requests per day quota

Comment: Can you show how you're going about the auth?

Comment: Hi @JeffreyGodwyll , earlier it was working fine. so, Please suggest, how should I pass it as authenticated ? I am using for ex: client = Googl.client('user@gmail.com', 'my_valid_password'). Any idea ?

Comment: https://github.com/zigotto/googl#server-side-web-applications `client = Googl::OAuth2.server("client_id", "client_secret", "redirect_uri")`

Comment: @rails-master have you resolved this issue.Now i am facing this issue Previously i used google-api-client -v 0.9.3. Now I updated to version 0.9.8 so i am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by using gem 'rqrcode_png', I created a method xyz and used this inside xyz method as :
`self.shortened_url = open(urlShortener uuid_url, "UserAgent" => "Ruby Script").read
 self.qr_code_url = RQRCode::QRCode.new("#{shortened_url}").to_img.resize(150, 150).to_data_url`

and called xyz method. That's It. My issue is resolved.